# Strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to write a program to display birth date using strings. Please check the code:

```
dob = int(input("enter your birth day"))
if dob > 31 or dob < 1:
   print("invalid")
mob = int(input("enter your birth month"))
if mob > 12 or mob < 1:
   print("invalid")
yob = int(input("enter your birth year"))
date = [dob, mob, yob]
bday = "Your birthday is on: {0}/{1}/{2}".format(date[0], date[1], date[2])
print(bday)
```

Output:

[image: output]

I want to make this program in a way that a valid date can be printed eg: 
32/23/2020 is invalid and therefore must not be printed.

Comment: `if dob > 31 **or** dob < 1:`

Comment: Think about your logic - can a number be simultaneously both larger than 31 *and* smaller than 1? Also, do all months have 31 days?

Comment: thank you for the and or thing, i m new in the programming field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
while True:
    dob = int(input("enter your birth day"))
    if not 1 <= dob <= 31:
       print("invalid")
       continue
    break


while True:
    mob = int(input("enter your birth month"))
    if not 1 <= mob <= 12:
       print("invalid")
       continue
    break
yob = int(input("enter your birth year"))
date = [dob, mob, yob]
bday = "Your birthday is on: {0}/{1}/{2}".format(date[0], date[1], date[2])
print(bday)
```

This code will ask for day and month until they will be valid and then insert the year and you will get the print statement to print validate date.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `or` operator, your value will never be greater than 31 **and** lower than 1 at the same time

```
if dob > 31 or dob < 1
    print("Invalid")
```

---

Also you may want to ask again until the value is valid, not just telling the use, use a while loop for that

```
dob = 0
while dob > 31 or dob < 1:
    dob = int(input("enter your birth day: "))

mob = 0
while mob > 12 or mob < 1:
    mob = int(input("enter your birth month: "))

yob = int(input("enter your birth year: "))

date = [dob, mob, yob]
bday = "Your birthday is on: {0}/{1}/{2}".format(*date) # * operator is for unpacking the list
print(bday)
```

Demo

```
enter your birth day: 32
enter your birth day: 35
enter your birth day: 15
enter your birth month: 55
enter your birth month: 20
enter your birth month: 10
enter your birth year: 1950
Your birthday is on: 15/10/1950
```

Comment: using while loop puts the program in loop of asking to enter the date/month/year. My motive is to print invalid if the date does not exist. any solutions?

Comment: @AaditeeDP if the day in invalid, just print Invalid and stop ? In this case just resuse your code and use `or` instead or `and`

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand it, it's simple:

```
dob = int(input("enter your birth day")) 
if dob not in range(1,32): 
    print("invalid") 

mob = int(input("enter your birth month")) 
if mob not in range(1,13) :
    print("invalid") 

yob = int(input("enter your birth year"))
if yob not in range(1900,2021):
    print("invalid")

date = [dob, mob, yob] 

bday = "Your birthday is on: {0}/{1}/{2}".format(date[0], date[1], date[2]) 
print(bday)
```

Comment: thank you for the help sir, but if we look at last statement it prints the invalid date.

Comment: I limited it between '1900'  and '2020', you can change it if want, will get correct result..